# php @chdir file not found

Tags: php, chdir

moved server hosts, the below used to work but now just get file not found

```
$cwd = getcwd();
@chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/avobb/');
include_once('./global.php');
chdir($cwd);
```

running FPM/FastCGI 7.3.17

```
path to global.php 
/var/www/vhosts/avoclub/htdocs/avobb/global.php
```

```
PHP Var
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']   /var/www/vhosts/avoclub/htdocs
```

Help

Comment: Why not simply `include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/avobb/global.php');` ?

Comment: Are you sure that `chdir` works correctly? It has an `@` operator before call. Maybe it fails for some reason and because of that `include_once` can't find a file.

Comment: ^-- Yes, that too. Could be nice to remove the `@` to get some warnings/error message

Comment: this is strange ! '''include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/avobb/global.php');''' still gives file not found !

Comment: ok more digging looks like it may be a PHP FPM issue. turned on loggin and go ```127.0.0.1 -  10/May/2020:10:54:48 +0100 "GET /documents/how_too/image.php" 404
'''

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a PHP Fpm issue closing this and raising new question